# in docbook xsl-fo can I determine if a table will be so wide it goes off the page

Tags: xsl-fo, docbook

I've got some wide tables that are being made in docbook and will be converted to a .fo file then a pdf. The tables are not being created by me so I have no control over their contents. I want to know if there's a way I can get the width of the table that's being output so I can determine if it's going to go off the page (or just some kind of flag it has if it goes off the page).

Comment: You should post a sample of the docbook XML you are looking at. I would think one could write XSL to sum up the col @width's (accounting for spanning) to do that if the table is a fixed layout, or maybe do it in the XSL that creates the FO and mark the table with a message.

Comment: You may want to read this thread which is one example of how it was done that way in a recursive XSL template. https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200105/msg00817.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XSLT Extensions from the Print & Page Layout Community Group (see https://www.w3.org/community/ppl/2015/02/18/getting-an-area-tree-within-your-xslt-transform/) and make decisions based on the Area Tree of the formatted tables.

See https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK189779/#graham-S3 for a description of a pre-PPL CG project that used the Area Tree to work out which width to use for each table -- column-wide, page-wide, or landscape -- before doing the final formatting.